# how to make it as arrow function

Tags: javascript

```js
function hypotenuse(a, b) {
  function square(x) { return x*x; }
  return Math.sqrt(square(a) + square(b));
}
console.log(hypotenuse(1,2))
```

i want to convert them as arrow function

Comment: Have you made an attempt yourself? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const square = (x) => x*x;
const hypotenuse = (a, b) => Math.sqrt(square(a) + square(b));
console.log(hypotenuse(1,2))
```

For more info you could read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=it).

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner:

```js
let hypotenuse = (a, b) => Math.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2);

console.log(hypotenuse(1,2));
```

Instead of using a dedicated function for squaring, I just used the [ES6 Shorthand for exponentiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation).

Comment: Something tells me they are not looking to shorten the code...the `square()` could be just an example for simplicity.

Comment: @vanowm Welp, it's an option. [@Giovanni Esposito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13897065/giovanni-esposito) already posted an answer that preserved the `square` function. OP can choose their preferred method